# using auto for having a distribution function with boost::random

Tags: c++, boost, random, functional-programming

I am trying to create a tuple where inside I will have a function that takes a generator and returns a double.

I still have difficulty to implement it.

So far I am trying to make such a line works :

```
    auto g = boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<>().operator()<boost::random::mt19937>;
```

and ideally use it like

```
#include <boost/random.hpp>

main()
{
    //I want to see all boost distribution as std::function<double(boost::random::mt19937)>
    auto g = boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<>().operator()<boost::random::mt19937>;
    boost::random::mt19937 f(0);
    double x = g(f);
}
```

I am missing something (surelly the fact that operator() is templated) but I don't understand why it doesn't compile on the auto.

Comment: What compiler and version do you use? If `clang++` or `g++` have you used the `-std=c++11` (or `-std=c++0x`) flag?

Comment: Also, if you want to use C++11 features, why not use the PRGN features now in [the library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)?

Comment: Yes I am linking against c++11 features with g++ 4.7.I do not use std:random for the moment for "human readness backward compatibility" :p

Comment: If you want an instance of the _function_ shouldn't you be using e.g. `boost::bind` (or `std::bind`) for that?

Answer (score 0):

Your expression creates a temporary first (`boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<>()`), then uses the `.` notation. The compiler interprets that as an attempt to access a member or **call a function** on that temporary (the function is `operator ()` in your case). However, the function call is missing arguments and parentheses, and that's syntactically illegal. This is the reason why it won't compile.

Anyway, if I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you basically want to have a functor which encapsulates `operator ()` of another object. However, I do not understand why you need one. If you have a functor in the first place, like `boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<>`, having another functor that only wraps its `operator ()` is kind of pointless.

Why can't you just do this?

```
boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<> g;    
boost::random::mt19937 f(0);
double x = g(f);
```